# UTC Timestamp to Datetime irrespective of TimeZone of server

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc

Below are the methods I use to convert UTC timestamp to equivalent DateTime in C#. So far so good when it was running in my local machine.

But started giving different time when we host it in a hosted environment running in Pacific Timezone (UTC-8:00)

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
{
 System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
 dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
 return dtDateTime;
}

    public static double ConvertDateToUnixTimestamp(DateTime value)
    {           
        TimeSpan span = (value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());          
        return (double)span.TotalSeconds;
    }
```

Input UTC Timestamp: 1447471800

Expected: `14/11/2015, 09:00:00` (In local machine its GMT + 5 :30)

Actual: `14/11/2015, 19:30:00`

If I remove the .ToLocalTime(), I am getting `14/11/2015, 03:30:00`

Below is the screenshot where we send the UTC timestamp from UI to server.

[image]

How do we handle this irrespective of timezone where the server is hosted.

From the above UI we send 1447471800 value to server using jQuery [fullcalender](http://fullcalendar.io/) control.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) instead of using `DateTime`.

Comment: This statement is wrong : new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());          Should be System.DateTimeKind.Utc not local time.   The variable value is already stored in the computer as UTC.  When a local time is enter in a computer it is converted to UTC automatically based on timezone.  Then any math is done using UTC time.  Then when time is outputted it is converted back to local time.